# How to install pdcurses

Tags: c, codeblocks, curses, pdcurses

I have been trying to install pdcurses for a long while, so I decided to just finally ask it on stack overflow.

Computer: windows 7

Language: C

Program: code::blocks

Compiler: MinGW: GNU GCC Compiler

Library: PDCurses 3.4

Is there any step by step guide to install the PDCurses library?

I have already tried using the console to make .a file, but I get an error after using the

`"mingw32-make -f mingwin32.mak"` command.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\pdcurs34\win32>mingw32-make -f mingwin32.mak
mingwin32.mak:14: C:\Program: No such file or directory
mingwin32.mak:14: Files: No such file or directory
mingwin32.mak:14: (x86)\CodeBlocks\pdcurs34/version.mif: No such file or directo
ry
mingwin32.mak:15: C:\Program: No such file or directory
mingwin32.mak:15: Files: No such file or directory
mingwin32.mak:15: (x86)\CodeBlocks\pdcurs34/libobjs.mif: No such file or directo
ry
mingwin32.mak:121: C:\Program: No such file or directory
mingwin32.mak:121: Files: No such file or directory
mingwin32.mak:121: (x86)\CodeBlocks\pdcurs34/makedist.mif: No such file or direc
tory
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target '(x86)\CodeBlocks\pdcurs34/makedist.mif
'.  Stop.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like mingwin32.mak has a problem with directories that have a space in them. Try putting the lbrary in a directory without a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like mingwin32.mak has a problem with directories that have a
>   space in them. Try putting the lbrary in a directory without a space.
>   – interjay

Interjay's solution worked.